# Ionic 2 with Google maps - Blank screen appear

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I guess it should be simple for the ionic/Angular people.
from some reason, I can't get this simple script to work (Ionic2 with GMaps).

Here is my code:
Map.html:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title>Google Map</ion-title>
  <ion-buttons end>
    <button (click)="addMarker()">
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>Add Marker
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content padding class="map">
  <div id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

Map.ts:

```
import {Page, NavController, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Geolocation} from 'ionic-native';

/*
  Generated class for the MapPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/map/map.html',
})
export class MapPage {
  constructor(public nav: NavController, platform: Platform) {
    this.nav = nav;
    this.map = null;
   // this.platform = platform;
   // this.initializeMap();

    this.platform = platform;

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.loadMap();
    });


  }
loadMap(){
  let options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((position) => {
      let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      let mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    });
  }
}
```

I have added my code here (Ionic2 project with Gmap inside):
http://plnkr.co/edit/ERnCxooM1IWD3qVLMQ1K?p=preview

you can find inside: "home.ts" the script, I have comment the code below, since in the moment I'm adding it back All of my ionic project is down, you can try and uncomment it.

I also have found Angular2 with Gmap project, But I couldn't find Ionic2 project with Gmap. here:

[Angular2 Gmap](http://plnkr.co/edit/YX7W20?p=preview)

Anyone can see what is wrong there?

Thank you very much!

Eran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an example app with ionic2 and google map.
https://github.com/nazrul104/google-map-with-ionic2. It may help you!

Comment: While the link might answer the question, the answer should contain the relevant part directly. Links can become stale.

Comment: Thank you very much, I went over the code and it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if you installed the plugin a correct way.
2. Validate your API keys at console.developers.google.com
3. Be sure the HTML element where the maps get injected into has a
   predefined height property.
4. Be sure you run your app on a connected or virtual
           device.

If that doesn't work: I've created an **Ionic 2.0.0-rc.5** starter with minimal functionality https://github.com/0x1ad2/ionic2-starter-google-maps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Nazrul here is the changes I made in my ts page file:

```
export class Page1 {
  constructor() {
     this.loadMap();

  }
   loadMap(){
  let options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
    //ENABLE THE FOLLOWING:

    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((position) => {
      let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      let mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('#map'), mapOptions);
      var x = document.querySelector('#map');
      console.log(x);
    });
  }

}
```

Now I can see the map :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was, do not initialize the map on the constructor, initialize it on the ionViewDidLoad.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
   console.log('ionViewDidLoad Maps');
   setTimeout(()=>{
      this.loadMap();
   }, 1000)
```

}