# Empty ion-content with google-map - Ionic2

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic2

I'm developing a page in ionic2 in order to handle google map.
But my ion-content display nothing. My `html` page contains the following code:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>{{text.title}}</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div #map id="map"></div>  
</ion-content>
```

While my `ts` file contains:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Recosh } from '../../providers/recosh';

declare var google;

@Component({
    selector: 'page-search',
    templateUrl: 'search.html'
})
export class SearchPage {

  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;
    text: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public recoshService: Recosh, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
        this.text = {
            title   :   this.recoshService.getMessage(1),
        }
  }

  ionViewLoaded(){
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap(){
    console.log("loading maps...");
    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.9290, 138.6010);

    let mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

  }
}
```

and the `src/index.html` has the following row as well:

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=*************"></script>
```

When I start my ionic2 project ( `ionic serve` ), while loading the page the map is not shown.

The created key on google APIs has no restriction, and it was done with my active API  Google Maps JavaScript API.

I thought it was a problem with APIs so I added all the following:

```
 Google Maps Android API
 Google Maps Directions API
 Google Maps Geocoding API
 Google Maps Geolocation API
 Google Maps JavaScript API
 Google Maps SDK for iOS
 Google Places API for Android
 Google Places API for iOS
 Google Places API Web Service
```

But my page still does not show any map.

The strange thing is that my console.log in the loadMap() function it is not shown in the console of my web browser (chrome); so it seems that loadMap is not called at all...

There are actually some warnings in my app but they appear before entering in the page:
[image]

Comment: Sorry but I don't see a console.log inside your ionViewLoaded and loadMap functions. In this way is impossible to detemine by chrome console if function is running or not.

Comment: it was just an example, however I updated the question in order to include it.

Comment: Fine, maybe your component is never been called. Your html page is called search.html? Where did you put page-search selector?

Comment: the page itself it is loading because I can see it and the title, just the map is not shown. If I write something inside the <div> it is also shown. The `app.modules.ts` is correctly set.

Comment: If you say so, it's not easy to identify the problem. Did you take a look to this module? I use it and it works well. https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Comment: Otherwise take a look to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183568/ionic-2-with-google-maps-blank-screen-appear?rq=1

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is due to my `.scss` file which up to now is empty, but even by trying to write inside the following row: `{page-home{#map{width:100%;height:100%;}}`, it seems not working...

Comment: Ok, did you try to something like that? {page-home{#map{width:500px;height:500px;}}

Comment: Yes I did, but it is not enough... I tried to call the loadMap() function by a pressure of a button and it works fine! So it is a problem related on calling the loadMap() in ionViewLoaded(). I tried also calling it in the constructor but it gives me error related the nativeElement (mapElement seems to be undefined at that stage).

Comment: ummm. did you try to use ngOnInit instead of ionViewLoaded?

Comment: well it seems that by using ngOnInit() it is working... how come?

Comment: ngOnInit is similar to ionViewLoaded. Take a look to angular2 lifecycle: (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) and to ionic2 lifecycle(https://webcake.co/page-lifecycle-hooks-in-ionic-2/) to understand which phase is better for you.

Comment: But I think that now it is generating me the problem explained in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877161/ionic2-no-updates-displayed-in-a-page

Answer (score 0):

Just put the map component outside of ion-content

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{text.title}}</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content></ion-content>

<div #map id="map"></div>
```