# Ionic2: no updates displayed in a page

Tags: google-maps, ionic2

I have a page in my ionic2 project where there is a marker in the google.maps.
When I move this marker (by dragging) it updates the lat and long position, making new search in my database and so displaying the new results.

The class of this page is the following:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
...

declare var google;

@Component({
    selector: 'page-search',
    templateUrl: 'search.html'
})

export class SearchPage {
    @ViewChild('map') mapElement    : ElementRef;
    map                             : any;
    guideList                       : Array<Guide>;
    text                            : any;
    lat                             : any; 
    lon                             : any;

    constructor (public navCtrl : NavController, public recoshService: Recosh, public alertCtrl : AlertController) {
            this.text = {
                title   :   this.recoshService.getMessage(1),
            }

            if(!this.recoshService.getOkGps()) this.showError(this.recoshService.getMessage(782));

            this.refresh(); 
    }

    refresh(){
        console.log("refresh called!");
        this.lat = this.recoshService.getLat();
        this.lon = this.recoshService.getLon();
        this.loadGuides();
    }

    ngOnInit(){ 
        this.loadMap();
    }

    loadGuides() {
        console.log("loading guides...");
        this.recoshService.getGuides().subscribe(
            (data)=>{
                if(data.success){
                    this.guideList = data.supports;
                    for(var i=0; i< this.guideList.length; i++){
                        if(this.guideList[i].guide==this.recoshService.getMyName()){
                            this.guideList.splice(i,1);
                            i--;
                            //break;
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    this.showError(this.recoshService.getMessage(data.message));
                }
            },
            (err) => {
                this.showError(err);
            }
        );
    }

    myInvitations() {
        this.navCtrl.push(InvitationsPage);
    }

    mySupports() {
        this.navCtrl.push(MySupportsPage);
    }

    showError(msg) {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Error',
            subTitle: msg,
            buttons: ['OK']
        });
        alert.present();
    }

    loadMap(){
        let mapOptions = {
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat,this.lon),
            zoom:5
        }

        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: this.map.getCenter(),
            icon: {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.BACKWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
                scale: 5,
                strokeWeight:2,
                strokeColor:"#B40404"
            },
            draggable:true,
            map: this.map,
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', () => {
            this.recoshService.setLon(marker.getPosition().lng());
            this.recoshService.setLat(marker.getPosition().lat());
            console.log("refreshing...");
            this.refresh();
            console.log("refreshing done!");
        });
    }
}
```

But the behaviour is very strange.
At the first entrance in the page, it takes correctly the user position and displaying the related results. By moving the marker the variables (lat, lon, guideList) are updated BUT no-updates are displaied on the browser. So the issue is that the variables observed by my html file are not updating the data even if they change

```
<guide-view *ngFor="let g of guideList" [guide]="g"></guide-view>
...
<ion-label>{{lat}}</ion-label>...<ion-label>{{lon}}</ion-label>
```

But if by navigating I pop it this page and then push it again, everything works correctly! All updateds are done immediatly on drag action and shown into the browser as well.

I wanna highlight that I am using `ngOnInit()` instead on `onIonicViewLoad()` else the map will not be shown as described in another question:
[Empty ion-content with google-map - Ionic2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42761780/empty-ion-content-with-google-map-ionic2?noredirect=1#comment72676556_42761780)

So based on the situation up to now I'm solving this issue in a "bad way", by opening this page by performing a push,pop,push actions:

```
this.navCtrl.push(SearchPage);
this.navCtrl.pop();
this.navCtrl.push(SearchPage);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `g` parameter using one-way binding. At this moment, `g` is just as input property,  when we drag the marker, the value does not go to the controller and then back and forth.

Did you try to use two-way binding?
https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/app_structure/two_way_data_binding.html

Let me know if this could help you.

Comment: Can you better explain it with a code example related to my class?